# Has a spoken language ever borrowed a word from a signed language?

Tags: sign-languages, borrowing

There are plenty of examples of signed languages borrowing or deriving words from spoken language. In ASL, the word DOG is a lexicalized fingerspelling of "dog", CHURCH is made with the "c" handshape corresponding to the first letter of "church", just to name a few.

Are there any examples of a spoken language borrowing words from a signed language? It seems less likely, since signed languages have lower prestige. Even so, there are many communities that have a large deaf population where such a phenomenon could happen.

Comment: Those examples are derived from the written language, though, not the spoken language. Glyph→sign is one thing, phone→sign is difficult for me to get my head around.

Comment: @StoneyB That's true, although there is some phone→sign effects with mouthing. For example, the sign FAT is often accompanied with mouth movement corresponding to the spoken word "fat". That said, an example of sign→glyph would also be interesting.

Comment: You could also look at it as phone→glyph→sign. I have been surprised so many times in linguistics that I'm prepared for the possibility of a surprise to exist here too. Voting up `(-:`

Comment: Well, one theory of the origin of Roman numerals is that I-X derived from hand signs, with the Is representing fingers,  V representing a spread hand, and X representing two hands. That would certainly represent sign→glyph, albeit not from a signed language.

Comment: It's not clear to me how this could happen. Would the speaker not say anything but instead sign the word?

Comment: Yes, I routinely see non-deaf people use ASL gestures that are identical to the ASL equivalent. (Including non-iconic ones, ie. including ones that are unlikely to be independently invented on the spot) An example was Charlie Sheen of all people signing "perfect" (during a spoken sentence with that word). I sometimes accidentally use ASL when talking to non-deaf, so I imagine that is how it creeps into the host language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any ASL signs that have made it into mainstream English, but there are a few things that are used typically by people who are part of the Deaf community when talking to each other. The English phrase "true biz" is used quite a bit both in writing and in spoken communicate. It comes from the gloss for a compound in ASL that means "actually." An exact translation of the compound might be REAL-WORK or TRUE-BUSINESS. Community members will also use the word "pah" to mean "finally" which comes from the non-manual marker that accompanies the manual sign for success.

Answer (score 6):

I guess most signed languages are known to too few speaking people for
such an occurrence to be likely. It is not so much a matter of prestige as a matter of population size and communication.

However, there are also very limited
signed languages used by speaking people when they have to communicate
silently or from a distance. It would have a better chance for "word
borrowing" from the signed to the spoken language.

Thinking of that, I did think of one expression in English that seems
to answer the question: "*to give the finger*" (sorry if that example
may break some rules - this is linguistics here).  There are probably
some others examples. Maybe, "*to wave someone goodbye*" would qualify too.

The interesting point about "*to give the finger*" is that it can be used in contexts where it is not actually describing a physical movement, but can be interpreted directly as meaning strong refusal.

A similar analysis applies to "*waving goodbye*", meaning "aknowledging
departure or loss". It can sometimes refer a description of the
actual signed gesture, like "*giving the finger*". But it clearly only have the abstract acknowledgement
meaning when applied to something other than a person. For example, in
the sentence "if you trust bankers, you can wave your savings
goodbye".

There are also counter-examples.

The expression "*Back-scratching*" refers to exchange of favor, not to
actual physical scratching. However, it is irrelevant here because
scratching someone's back is not considered a mean of communication.

The expression "*to nod approval*" does refer to the signed gesture of
approval, but (afaik) is only used to actually describe the signed
gesture. One would not say "*the man nodded*" to mean that he expressed
agreement by any mean, but only to mean that he expressed agreement by
actually nodding. So the verb "*to nod*" cannot be considered as
borrowed from the signed language, but only as a reference to it.